Parameterize Kotlin import statements?
I am trying to implement two build flavors, as follows:
    productFlavors {
    myApp1 {
        dimension "app-types"
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp1"
    }
    myApp2 {
        dimension "app-types"
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp2"
    }

I have many kotlin statements in this general form, across my Kotlin modules:
import com.mycompany.myapp1.mymodule.SomeModule

So, if I use the "myApp1" build flavor, my import statement works.  If I switch to "myApp2" flavor, it no longer works.
Obviously, I need to parameterize the ".myapp1." part.
How do I do this in Kotlin?
Thanks, Charles

When you work with different build flavors in Android, you should keep the namespace constant while using different applicationId for different flavors.
android {
    compileSdk 34
    namespace 'mycompany.myapp'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mycompany.myapp" //it could be different than namespace
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "app-types"
            applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp1"
        }
        stag {
            dimension "app-types"
            applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp2"
        }
    }
}

namespace defines your package structure. For example, if the namespace is mycompany.myapp then all of your imports should be changed like:
import com.mycompany.myapp.mymodule.SomeModule


Interesting.  So, does that mean the different applicationId's will ensure that the apk's install in different directories on the target Android system?
Something like /data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp1/* or /data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp2/*

This worked pretty well for me!  Thanks for the tip!

You're welcome, Charles. Happy Coding!

Your package name for code doesn't need to be the same as the package name for your apk.  In fact you'll be using a lot of code in libraries whose package name is nothing like your app's.  Just name them independently.

I sort of got that impression while I was figuring out how to create an "app-types" flavor dimension.  However, I don't know how to name "them" (whatever 'them is, btw) independently.
I'm inheriting code from a previous app-developer, and Android app dev is still new to me.  This has me quite stumped.

The package name is from the package command at the top of the file.  Just change that to whatever you want.  Or pick one of those two and stick with it, as that can be literally anything.  By convention you generally put it into a folder structure with the same name as the package (so com.example.foo becomes com/example/foo) but I believe in Kotlin that's not enforced.  Either way the refactor tool in Android Studio can do that for you.


I need to parameterize the ".myapp1." part. How do I do this in Kotlin?

That is not an option, sorry. You might try to minimize the amount of code that refers to code-generated items that wind up in com.mycompany.myapp1 or com.mycompany.myapp2 sub-packages (e.g., R classes), then isolate that code in flavor-specific source sets or modules.

so, fending off these import statements with a buildconfig definition (similar to what is done with the C/C++ pre-processor #ifdef / #endif) bloc is not possible either?

@CharlesMartin There is no equivalent of a preprocessor in Kotlin or Java.  There are some tools that can do something like that, but you'd have to build it into the build system yourself.  It's not recommended.

So, I've decided to try and bundle my common-code in an Android library, as I've read on S/O and from the above replies.
Thanks again for your input!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
